# transitive dependency management in jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, dependency-management

I have a maven `project`, which has lots of data-streaming processors and drop-wizard services.

Amongst them, are `db-source` - holds all the `DAO`s and `Entities` & `client-source` - holds external services end-points, these are used by all the *apps* in the `project`. 
So far, dependency of these are individually added by each child app in their own pom and its now supposed to me moved to common versioning using `<dependencyManagement>` on `project`s POM.

This is the project structure on the surface

```
+ project
    + db-source - pom.xml => picks version from build.properties
    + client-source  - pom.xml => picks version from build.properties
    + fabric - pom.xml => has db and client and there versions are picked from project_POM
    + the_pain_repo - pom.xml => uses fabric and picks its version from project_POM
+ project_POM
```

`project_POM` contains the `<dependencyManagement>` for versions of `db-source` and `client-source` which is being used in `fabric` and other repos ( `the_pain_repo` is one of the sample repos mentioned )

So, if you observe, `<dependencyManagement>` is as below

```
   ==> fabric -> project_POM
   ==> the_pain_repo -> fabric -> project_POM
```

Now, fabric builds fine after picking version from `project_POM` but `the_pain_repo` throws error that it cant pick `db-source` ( which is coming from `fabric`) version.

Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project inventory-processor: Could not resolve dependencies for project x.y.z:the_pain_repo:jar:1.7.4-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: x.y.z:db-source:jar:${db.source.version}, 
 x.y.z:client-source:jar:${client.source.version}: Could not find artifact x.y.z:client-source:jar:${client.source.version} in systems-artifactory (http://artifactory.systems.com/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

values as in Jenkins :

```
Root POM :  the_pain_repo/pom.xml
Properties File Path : the_pain_repo/build.properties
```

Comment: The "master" POM sounds like an organizational parent or BOM and should be being deployed to the usual artifact repository.

Comment: my bad, have added more details to make sense, in nutshell, its not org level POM but within a team!!

Comment: That's still "organizational" in that it's a common component reused for multiple projects that aren't intertangled technically, and the usual recommendations apply: It's either a parent or a BOM, and manage it as first-class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy parent pom to your maven repository (or artifactory). You can try this out by doing a `mvn clean install` or `mvn -N clean install` (for parent module only) to deploy this to your local `.m2`